# Singlethreaded ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with calls limit

Tags: concurrency, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I would like to utilize the java.util.concurrent.Executors to fire some runner.
The problem is that i wanted to fire it fixed amount of times. It is important to call those runners a fixed rate.

For me it is perfectly sufficient use a Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor so i wonder  why this is not possible ....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to aproach this with TimerTask but the same effect.
Problem is how to effectively, elegant and treadsafely - shutdown TimerTask, ScheduledExecutorService after certain number of calls ...

Comment: I found some solution + but i guess it has the chance to quite stable for _Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor_. I just cancel ScheduledFuture directly in my Runnable/Callable upon by condition. The ScheduledFuture is gotten as the executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable,....)